# getNodeValue() returns some random string

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an android project with file res/raw/lvl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"?>

<Level>

  <dimensions>
    <a>5</a>
    <b>5</b>
  </dimensions>

    .
    .
    .
</Level>
```

My java code is following

```
InputStream input = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lvl);
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = buider.parse(input);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dimensions");
Node node = nList.item(0);
int a = Integer.parseInt(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim());
```

The last line throws parsing exception, node.getNodeValue().trim() is "\t\t\n\t".

Comment: what error u are getting ?

Comment: The last line will throw an exception because next node is the whitespace between <dimensions> and <a>. If node.getFirstChild() doesn't return an element, you should iterate the siblings until you find an element node.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the `<dimensions>` tag, not at `a` and `b`. Look:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dimensions");
Node node = nList.item(0);
int a = Integer.parseInt(node.getNodeValue().trim());
```

You're getting the first (index `0`) element of name `dimensions`. Not its children.

The value you see (`\t\t\n\t`) is what's left of `dimensions`' contents after children nodes are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Could not understand what exactly you are trying to do ...but .. you can refer below if that helps

```
public class Parsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        Parsing parse = new Parsing();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("x.xml"));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dimensions");
        Node node = nList.item(0);
        for (Node childNode = node.getFirstChild();
                childNode != null;) {
            //do something 
            System.out.println(childNode.getNodeName());
            System.out.println(childNode.getTextContent());
            Node nextChild = childNode.getNextSibling();
            childNode = nextChild;
        }
    }
}
```